# Upgrade a simple select/unselect into a proper array I can call on

Tags: angularjs, select, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I have an ng-repeat that shows a list of items a user can 'select' and I am using the following code (stripped down example) for the selection process

```
<div class="panel" ng-class="{'titleSelected': titleSelected[$index]}" ng-repeat="item in listofitems">
<h1>{{item.name}}</h1>
<button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="titleSelected[$index] = !titleSelected[$index]">
<span ng-hide="titleSelected[$index]">Add to Buy List</span>
<span ng-show="titleSelected[$index]">Remove from Buy List</span>
</button>
</div>
```

Now this is working fine (I have also had this working using item.id to track rather than $index. i click an item, background changes colour thanks to ng-class and the button dynamically becomes a remove button

However I was expecting titleSelected to be an array of stored info, but I was clearly wrong. What I actually need is a live array that stores / removes item.id on click and I have approached this all wrong.

Also when I use filters (not shown in the code), if any item is selected and then hidden by the filters.. and brought back it loses its 'selected' status.

This is the case with both $index and item.id

I suspect little functions with push and splice are required but I also still need the simple functionality of the add remove in place as well. and in perfect sync with what has actually been selected

Any pointers appreciated

EDIT 1 : Ok by simply adding

```
$scope.titleSelected = [];
```

into my controller, and using item.id instead of $index my app is now 1) remembering the selected items between filter changes AND createing an array I can call on. However the array contains (on the first selection) an entry for every single item.

So I have 503 items, and on first click the array length jumps to 912 (no idea where this number comes from).. most of which are null, but if I click on the item with id=4 then the fourth entry becomes true i.e

```
null,null,null,true,null...
```

Answer (score 0):

Done with a couple of functions bound to ng-click

```
$scope.basket=[];

$scope.addToBasket = function(item) {
    $scope.basket.push(item);
};

$scope.removeFromBasket = function(item) {
    var index = $scope.basket.indexOf(item);
    if (index > -1) {
        $scope.basket.splice(index, 1);
    }
};
```

and in the HTML

```
<button ng-hide="titleSelected[item.id]" class="btn btn-success" 
ng-click="addToBasket(item.id);titleSelected[item.id] = !titleSelected[item.id]">
          Add to Buy List
        </button>

<button ng-show="titleSelected[item.id]" class="btn btn-success" 
ng-click="removeFromBasket(item.id);titleSelected[item.id] = !titleSelected[item.id]">
              Remove from Buy List
            </button>
```